# How to create a table where one value occures only once for another value

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a table which stores the attendance of employees, I have 6 columns, (employee code, status, in time, out time, total time, date) I want to create the table in such a way that the date for an employee code shouldn't be repeated i.e the attendance for one day of employee can't be added again. Is there a way by which I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To guarantee the unicity of `(employee_code, date)` tuples, you can simply make these columns the primary key of the table (or set a unique constraint on it):

```
CREATE TABLE attendance (
    employee_code INT, 
    status INT, 
    in_time TIME, 
    out_time TIME, 
    total_time INT, 
    `date` DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(employee_code, `date`)
);
```

Note: `date` is not a good pick for a column name, since it conflicts with homonym MySQL datatype. I would suggest to choose another name.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gNBefAEq1ajZoeqpV9wQFW/1)**:

First create the table then insert once:

```
INSERT INTO attendance(employee_code, `date`) values (1, NOW());
```

When trying to insert again the same tuple, then, you get error:

> Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '1-2019-09-28' for key 'PRIMARY'